# Specify schema output for BigQuery View

Tags: sql, view, google-bigquery

I have a query which joins three tables, selecting only the columns I want to keep with a view as the output.

Some of the columns in the output have slightly different data types than I would want.

For example some are string where I would like boolean, some are string where I would like integer.

Is there a way to specify the table schema?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Without more information about the data it is difficult to understand what is the issue. However you might want to cast the column to the type you want https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules